# React inline styles syntax changes

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

When I try to use inline styles flex attribute it's changed. This:

```
<div style={{ flex: '1' }}></div>
```

becomes

```
<div style="flex: 1 0 0px;"></div>
```

I can't figure out where the heck it comes from.

Or is it a core React bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited) Explaination is that React is trying to be clever and follow the standards but IE11 isn't following it or just too buggy in it's implementation of flexbox.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <div style={{ flex: '1 0 auto', border: '1px dotted #ccc' }}>
          Hello 
        </div>
        <div style={{ flex: '1 0 auto' }}>
          or 
        </div>          
        <div style={{ flex: '1 0 auto', border: '1px dotted #ccc' }}>
          world 
        </div>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/313712/ (ironically jsfiddle doesn't support IE11)

Only workaround I've found is to add the flex: 1; in a stylesheet loaded by react.

Created an issue on their github also: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13859